# htmlpurifier nofollow only working for generated links

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm using the HTML purifier library for my website's comment formatting.

However, I noticed something. In my settings, I have HTML.nofollow set to true.

```
'HTML.Nofollow' => true,
```

But when I write an anchor link, nofollow won't be added. But with a generated link, it'll work just fine.

**Example Input:**

```
<a href="www.google.com">google</a>

https://www.yahoo.com
```

**Output:**

```
<p><a href="www.google.com">google</a></p>

<p><a href="https://www.yahoo.com" rel="nofollow">https://www.yahoo.com</a></p>
```

Here are my settings:

```
return [
    'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
    'finalize'      => true,
    'cachePath'     => storage_path('app/purifier'),
    'cacheFileMode' => 0755,
    'settings'      => [
        'default' => [
            'HTML.Doctype'             => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
            'HTML.Allowed'             => 'b,i,u,ul,ol,li,p,blockquote,table,tr,th,td,a[href|title],sup,sub,span,code',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => true,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
            'AutoFormat.Linkify' => true,
            'HTML.Nofollow' => true,
        ],

    ],

];
```

I would be fine removing  as one of the allowed HTML elements, but for some reason this means generated URLs don't work at all anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="www.google.com">google</a>`, as it lacks a scheme (`http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, etc.), is *actually* a link to something like `http://example.com/www.google.com` (depending if you're in a folder of your site or not). As `nofollow` is typically used to prevent *other* sites from stealing link juice, relative links like this are probably exempt.

Try it with something like this instead:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
```

<sup>(As a bonus, the link will actually work this way.)</sup>